# "failed while installing axis2 core 1.1" in eclipse?

Tags: java, apache, web-services, apache-axis

hello every one i am working java web service where i need to use axis 2 . i follow the some tutorial for resolve this issue ..

Steps which i followed

1) i selected Windows option and then its sub option -> Preferences.

2) Then i selected the axis web services and select the axis run time.

3) Then i gave the path of my axis2 binary and i got the "Axis2 Loaded successfully" message.

4) Then i create the dynamic web project with module 2.5 and then process next then i got this error.

[image]

i am traveling on web from 3 days but not find any solution for this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finaly i solve this error by doing some changes which is follows as below steps

Step 1) I use latest eclipse juno

Step 2) i selected Windows option and then its sub option -> Preferences and give it to the path of the axis binary..

Step 3) Then i create dynamic web application with 2.5 module without default run time

and then next.. and i my problem is slove ....

Answer (score 2):

### The steps in detail are as follows

1. Go to eclipse > top menu bar > Window > preferences
2. Click on **Webservices**
3. Click on **Axis2 Preferences**
4. Enter the location of the axis2 install (for example if it is installed in C:\) 
   then it becomes C:\axis2-1.6.4.
5. Restart eclipse.

Comment: Just to add, in the step 4, axis has to be downloaded on his website....

Answer (score 1):

please use stable version with axis 2 api and then follow these steps :

Step 1) use stable version of eclipse kliper.q

Step 2) Select Windows option and then sub option -> Preferences and give it to the path of the axis distribution.

Step 3) Create dynamic web application with 2.5 module with server you required and then hit next.

Step 4) Create java class with your business logic and lunch it as service for wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with all versions of eclipse.

The checkout of the project had a new folder called axis2-web, which created this problem. Hence a fresh checkout of the web project helped me solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It´s no needed to use the last version of Eclipse, only install axis2 and then configure the environment. I installed axis2 version "axis2-1.6.4", then my project was created successfully. The system is looking for axis2 binaries.

Regards,

HR